# Logs not visible while npm task is running

Tags: azure-devops

In AzureDevops, when running an NPM task on a private agent, the logs are not visible until the task completes.

The output just appears blank e.g.

[image]

This happens for all npm tasks, from tasks that result in large log output and small.
The task above is a long running task which uses TestCafe to perform functional UI tests on a website. However, the same happens for other npm commands such as install.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?Does the log display return to normal? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested npm tasks, the log can be loaded normally:

[image]

Here are a few points you can try to see if it returns to normal:

1. What version of npm are you using? If not latest,you can try the latest npm task version.
2. According to your interface, you are using an older version of UI , you can try to enable `Multi-stage pipelines` in Preview features.

   [image]
3. Try to run with [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and see if it's still the same.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my description to include the fact that it's running on a private agent. I'll try enabling multi-stage pipelines.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Can MS hosted agent shows npm task with custom command like npm run and be able to tail the log and watch it while running?  I don't seem to find a way to see the output of mocha test until the test is finished.